Installing Packet Tracer
I get the following error when trying to install Packet Tracer.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'packettracer' instead of './Packet_Tracer822_amd64_signed.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 packettracer : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

How do I resolve this issue?

You seem to have downloaded a deb file, but decided to install the repository version anyway. Is that correct?
